# Query document where includes reference document

Tags: mongoose

how do i query a document based on found reference doucments.

so i do this query:

```
    const user_reservations = await TimeSlot.findOne({
      user_id: user._id,
    });
```

and now i want to find parent document like so:

```
await Schedule.find({
      timeSlots: user_reservations,
    })
```

this is does not give back a valid query.

i tried looping through user_reservations and querying timeslots based on id:

```
user_reservations.map(async (d) => {
      await Schedule.findOne().populate({
        path: "timeSlots",
        match: { _id: d._id },
      });
    });
```

this also does nothing.

Comment: I miss the context here, but why not use an aggregation, something like this? `TimeSlot.aggregate([ { $match: { user_id: user._id } }, { $lookup: { from: "schedules", localField: "user_id", foreignField: "timeSlots", as: "scheduleDoc" } }, { $unwind: "$scheduleDoc" } ])`

Comment: Can you add your schema models to the question?